# Почему нет NTFS в UEFI

Tags: ntfs, uefi

Здравствуйте!
У меня возник вопрос - почему в Uefi Development Kit нет пакета, который бы отвечал за поддержку NTFS? При этом пакет поддержки FatPkg присутствует.

Comment: Потому что NTFS проприетарная и закрытая и без документации?

Comment: А как же [**ЭТА ССЫЛКА**](http://www.dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf)?

Comment: Это неофициальная документация, полученная путём реверс-инжиниринка линуксоидами за бесплатно, доверять ей и тем более пилить UEFI на её базе — себя не уважать)

Comment: Большое спасибо. Догадки были в этом направлении, но хотелось чтобы кто-то подтвердил.